# Testcases for mobile apps on different devices

Tags: mobile, testcase

I am developing test-cases for some mobile apps for my organization.

Do I need to prepare different test cases for the same application for different devices like iPad, iPhone, Android, Blackberry?

What are the criteria where I can use the same test cases for all the devices and where should I write different test cases, so as to cover all possibilities with less effort and time.

Comment: It really depends on the app you are testing. If it re-uses code across different OS, you can re-use test cases against that code. If user scenarios are the same across different OS, your test cases for those scenarios can be re-used. If you're automating everything, write an abstraction layer to test the code with a single test case regardless of the OS.

Answer (score 2):

- Nowadays developers make a responsive application than not required to write different test cases for all application. Tester can write one time test case for general modules of application according to the project requirement for each platform.
- In which starting with the general test cases which is all most same for the Android , iPhone or window App like install , Uninstall, Registration , Login , Voice Call Handling ,Low Battery , Charger Effect etc
- After that every device platform OS have different  UI & UX then required to write the some different test cases for android, iphone ,Windows Application.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your requirements but I imagine the behavior and design are intended to be the same across all devices (assuming it's responsive). In this case you would only have one set of test cases, with maybe something special for Android's hardware buttons (menu, back, etc). Test this same set of standards across multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by defining your core functionality requirements, then work from there.

Keep as much of the testing as universal as possible, and break out into separate features/sheets for platform specifics.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your mobile app requirement. But note that the way some functionalities works is different in different Mobile OS. For example the way push notifications works in iOS is different than Android.

Also you need to consider UI guidelines for iOS and Android while writing test cases like iOS needs to have back button on UI while in Android its not necessary, More button representation in iOS and android, the way alerts are shown in iOS and Android, toast messages in Android etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you should create test cases for diff. devices if you want to check design specific. Mostly in IOS there is less possibility that you will get design issue device specific , But in Android devices there is huge chances for that.

You can use Excel to write test cases initially.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you need to write Test Cases for different Devices. In simple words just follow the "Compatibility Testing" or "Cross Browser Testing".